# How to calculate needed velocity for a ball to hit targer?

Tags: java, android, coordinates, velocity

I want to calculate velocity for ball to hit target(my ball/finger).
x and y of my ball are know and are changing while I'm moving my finger but assume that it is not changing (X and Y are some random number) and ball that should reach my finger is coming from left upper corner (x=0,y=0).
How to calculate velocityX and velocityY for that ball in order to hit me ?

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not algebra problems.

Comment: @MarcB, but OP tagged "Android" that certainly makes it fit for Stackoverflow /sarcasm

Comment: Read this official article: [Tracking Movement](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html)

Comment: I need that for my android app/game. @MarcB

Answer (score 0):

You could set velocityX to negative if the ball is X is greater then the target's X else set velocity to a positive number if it is less then the target's X. This would make the ball move towards the X coordinate of the target. Just do the same for the y Axis and the ball should move towards the target. However, this may cause the ball to "shake" when it reaches the target so, in order to fix this, set velocityX and velocity to 0 when it reaches the target.

Hope this helped.